# How can I put shipped items back in stock when returned by a customer?

Tags: inventory

Consider the following scenario:

1. Customer orders 3 items
2. Admin creates invoice and shipment, ships items out
3. Customer returns 1 of the 3 items

This all happens before the invoice is paid. So now we have to generate a new invoice. No problem, just cancel the existing (unpaid) invoice and create a new one for just the two items.

But I can't find a way to put the returned items back in stock right (except manually).

When the return happens after the invoice is paid, restocking the returned items is no problem, because when creating the Credit Memo I can tell Magento to put the refunded items back in stock. But I can't create a Credit Memo for an unpaid order...

What's the workaround here? Does the admin really have to restock the items manually, or am I overlooking something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hm, I suppose there is no "easy" way to solve this, so what I'm doing now is just canceling the invoice, then canceling the order and creating a new order with just the items that haven't been returned. The returned items are put back in stock automatically when the original order is cancelled.